# Room DB: Duplicate class issues with Dao and RoomDatabase classes

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a simple Room implementation in my app and am having issues with the Dao and RoomDatabase classes upon building the app (Build is failing).

1. Dao class is 'NoteDao'

   ```
   @Dao
   interface NoteDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    suspend fun getAllNotes(): List<Note>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE uid = :uid")
    suspend fun getNoteByUid(uid: Int): Note

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note): Long

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Note): Int
   }
   ```
2. RoomDatabase class

   ```
    @Database(
        entities = [Note::class],
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false
    )
    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun noteDao() : NoteDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) { instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it } }

        private fun buildDatabase(appContext: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "NADB")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }
   }
   ```
3. Note Entity

   ```
    @Entity(tableName = "notes")
    data class Note (
            @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
            val uid: Long,
            val title: String,
            val content: String,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") val imageUrl: String,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "created_on") val createdOn: Long,
            @ColumnInfo(name = "edited_on") val editedOn: Long
        )
   ```

Build Output errors -

1. NoteDao_Impl.java

> /Users/KK/StudioProjects/K-K/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/task/noteapp/data/daos/NoteDao_Impl.java:29:
> error: duplicate class: com.task.noteapp.data.daos.NoteDao_Impl public
> final class NoteDao_Impl implements NoteDao {

and

2. AppDatabase_Impl.java

> /Users/KK/StudioProjects/K-K/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/task/noteapp/data/local/AppDatabase_Impl.java:34:
> error: duplicate class: com.task.noteapp.data.local.AppDatabase_Impl
> public final class AppDatabase_Impl extends AppDatabase {

followed by -

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
>
> Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing

On further investigation, I found the following issues with the respective generated files -

1. NoteDao_Impl - class level error

> Class 'NoteDao_Impl' must either be declared abstract or implement
> abstract method 'getAllNotes(Continuation<? super List<? extends
> Note>>)' in 'NoteDao'

and within this class, the 'getAllNotes()' method had this error -

> getAllNotes(Continuation<? super List>)' in
> 'com.task.noteapp.data.daos.NoteDao_Impl' clashes with
> 'getAllNotes(Continuation<? super List<? extends Note>>)' in
> 'com.task.noteapp.data.daos.NoteDao'; both methods have same erasure,
> yet neither overrides the other

2. AppDatabase_Impl - class level error

> Duplicate class found in the file
> '/Users/KK/StudioProjects/K-K/app/build/generated/ksp/debug/java/com/task/noteapp/data/local/AppDatabase_Impl.java'

As far as I can see that my implementation of Room is not wrong. However, I can’t figure out the issues.

Dependencies -

> ```
> def room_version = "2.4.3"
> implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
> implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
> annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
> kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
> ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
> ```

Comment: can you share your dependencies version

Comment: @SohaibAhmed Done. Added in the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

kapt and ksp seems to be in conflict. Removing kapt seems to have solved the issue.

> kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

> ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

Answer (score 0):

Try this version,

```
def room_version = "2.5.0-beta01"
```

I found the same issue,, tried everything, it didn't work. Then I just update my dependencies of room along with navigational components. That fixed my problem.